# Interpreting Bytes Per Sector on FAT32 Volume Boot Record

Tags: parsing, fat32, mbr, sector

Below I've attached an image pertaining to the following question. I am parsing the volume boot record for a FAT32 partition and was stuck for many hours until I figured out WinHex has a Data Interpreter. When I click on 0Bh it shows a 16 bit interpretation which equals 512.

My question is, how does the system get 512 out of this. Does it read the bytes per sector in Big Endian or something similar? I'm simply confused on this one... The picture shows the VBR in WinHex.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCGIS.png

Comment: 00 02 is low endian interpreted as (0 + 2*256)

Comment: Why is it 2*256? And how am I supposed to know this and how does WinHex know to do this?

Comment: It's 2*256 for the same reason as 1234 = 1*1000 + 2*200 + 3*30 + 4. The 'base' of a byte is 256. Base of a single bit is 2 and base of a hex digit is 16. 1234 in base of 100 would be 12*100 + 34. 'Low endian' ie. "reversed" compared to integer representation in natural languages is one of two most common design choices made for integer representation in computers.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will become more clear in the weeks to come.

Comment: Did you get the answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The values are in little endian, thus `00,02` is `0200` the bytes are reversed, thus `02` comes first then `00`.

`0x0200` in base 10 is 512.